# How do I bring back a clicked on "easier to read code display"?

Tags: intellij-idea

I notice that IDEA has this ability to render "raw" type parameters in java in such a way that it is easier to read. so if I have this class

```
class MarginInfo {
  MarginInfo( boolean top, boolean right, boolean left, boolean bottom ) {
```

when calling it, the actual code is

```
new MarginInfo( true, true, true, true );
```

But it renders as

```
new MarginInfo( top: true, right: true, left: true, bottom: true );
```

once you click on the rendered code, it rerenders as the actual code. After clicking the code, even if editing elsewhere it stays as the actual code. Is there any way to get IDEA to have a signature go back to rendering in the "easier to read" format after clicking? (also does this feature have a name?)